# Difficulty showing run-time is bigOmega(g(n))

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm having some trouble with the following algorithm:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = 2i)
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        // do something (const time)
```

So it wasn't too hard showing that runtime is O(nlogn) - but I'm not sure how to show that it's Big Omega(nlogn)! Intuitively, I see that it must be the case, since for a given n, time complexity doesn't vary between best / worst case.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: If you can find a constant `c1` to show `f(n) < c1*nlogn` for some n0 greater than 0, it should be trivial to find a `c2` to show `c2*nlogn < f(n)` for some n0 greater than 0

Comment: Right - could I say that the inner loop has to execute at least n/2 times, so c is 1/2?

Comment: well the inner loop executes `n + (n-2) + (n-4) + (n-8)... ` times and we know we will have `log(n)` of the `(n-i)` summations, so if we separate it out (thanks to commutativity/associativity) we should show the inner loop executes `n + n + n ... - 2 - 4 - 8 -...`, so we have `n*logn` for the count of `n's` and we sum `2^i` from `i = 1 to logn` which equals `2^(logn+1) -1`, which we can reduce to `2n-1`. Use this information to setup the inequality and find a `c2`

Comment: Ok.. so by your calculations, this algorithm is in fact O(n) and not O(nlogn)?

Comment: No - and my math was (very slightly off). I will move this to an answer as I should have before the last post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the intuition behind why this is O(nlogn), all we need to do is see how many times the inner loop executes.

As you have said, the outer loop executes `logn` times (easy to see, as you can only double `i` `logn` times before the inequality stops holding)

So for the inner loop, we can see it executes a different amount of steps each time `i` changes

The first iteration, it executes `n-1` times (as `i` starts at `1`)

The next iteration, `n-2`

The third iteration, `n-4`

We can see the pattern is `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-4) + (n-8) ...`

Now, let's separate out the `n's` together. How many `(n-k)` additions do we have? We have `logn` of them by knowing thats how many times the outer loop executes.

So `n + n + n + n ... - 1 - 2 - 4 - 8...` can be thought of as `nlogn - 1 - 2 - 4 - 8 ...`

Now, how do we show this can be reduced even further? Well the total number of subtractions we have is `logn` subtractions (thanks to the outer loop), and we know the size of the subtraction keeps doubling each time. Another way to look at it is the sum from `i = 0 to logn` of `2^i`.

Now a standard CS formula is `sum of i = 0 to n` of `2^i` is `2^(n+1) - 1`. This is used to show the max number of nodes in a complete binary tree, for example, and you can prove it by induction.

So we substitute `logn` for `n` in the formula, and we get `nlogn - (2^(logn+1)- 1)` . But we aren't done yet. We can show that `2^(logn+1) = 2*2^logn=2*n`. So finally, we end up with `nlogn - 2n + 1`. At this point, set up your inequality and find a `c2`.

Answer (score 1):

In this algorithm, there is no best- or worst-execution path: given a value for `n`, the execution path is fixed. So the best and worst cases are the same.

A good rule of thumb is that, if the control flow of the algorithm is not data-driven, then the best and worst cases are the same.

An example of what I mean by data-driven would be an implementation of the quicksort algorithm in which the pivot is always chosen to be the first element of the array. Sometimes that first element will split the rest of the data perfectly (best case) and sometimes it will be a maximum or minimum (worst case).

Comment: Right that makes sense, but suppose we want to show that more rigorously. Would we actually have to derive an explicit function for run time? What would it look like in this case?

Comment: I'm thinking f(n) is the summation from 1 to logn of (j - i), but I don't see how I could take it further to show it is in fact Big Omega of nlogn

Comment: @codeMonkey17 This is 100% rigorous. You already gave the argument for why the worst case is O(n log n). You can extend that argument by saying control flow is completely determined by just the value of n. Therefore the best case is Omega(n log n).